# Faces black/flickering

Tags: faces

[image: How to clean the face. As seen in my image do help]

How do I make the two strange faces normal? I have tried several things with the normals, as shown in the gif, but nothing helps.

Comment: i try all the possibility normal flip, recalculate inside and outside but yet to i cant get the clean face or normal faces

Comment: cheeky question: how many faces are on top of each other? :)

Comment: Your model seems to be composed of several meshes. Check if they have overlapping faces.

Answer (score 0):

Those aren't Normals, those are Doubles
Just select "Remove Doubles" in mesh options (W)